# Check if an array of integers contain a integer a[i] such that a[i] = a[j]+a[k] where j,k<i and j!=k

Tags: arrays, algorithm

This is what I come up with

```
public static boolean pairEqualSum(int[] a) {
        for (int i = 2; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i - 1; j >= 1; j--) {
                for (int k = j - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
                    if (a[i] == a[j] + a[k]) {
                        System.out.println(i + " " + j + " " + k);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

I can only solve this with three loops which makes its time complexity O(n^3). 
Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Binary search ?

Comment: @intvprep Hey, at least say: Yes, No!, WRONG! or something other than silence that looks like I DO NOT CARE ANYMORE :). Really, if you ask and people try to help you and spend on it some time, it is nice at least to comment on theirs effort, even saying that theirs solution is wrong is good thing for community, we discuss, we learn, knowledge is improved. This way it looks like home work was done, or was not done, at you moved on.  Please consider, that this is why many people just stop trying to help. Do not apologize, do not thank us, just COMMENT!

Answer (score 0):

First we can solve another task: given an array of items, answer whether it is possible to create a number `X` from the sum of two elements.

In order to do this we can sort the array and introduce left and right locations.

```
L                 R  
1 3 8 13 15 19 44 178
```

Now we can perform two actions:

- Increase the sum by moving `L` to the right
- Decrease the sum by moving `R` to the left

Using these two actions we can answer the question in `O(n)`, by always maintaining `L+R`as close to `X` as possible. This approach results in overall algorithm complexity of `O(n*lg(n))` because of sort.

Using this algorithm you can achieve the final complexity of `O(n*n)` (considering that you'll sort array using all the items only once, and then just "enable" elements of array while moving `X`).

Comment: We cant sort the array as the requirement says a[i] = a[j]+a[k] where j,k < i. Problem statement does'nt allow sorting.

Comment: @intvprep, I guess you missed the part '"enable" elements of array while moving `X`'. Also you can use something like RB-tree and just maintain part of the array [0...i) sorted, while traversing.

Answer (score 0):

How about this way?

```
int[] arr[];
hashtable = init_hashtable();

for(int i = 2; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    if (hastable.Contains(arr[i])) return true;

    //we need combinations from orange vertical column
    for(int j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; j++)
    {
         int combination = arr[j] + arr[i-1];
         if (arr[i] == combination || !hashtable.Set(combination))
            return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

### [image: Previous elements combinations j,k < i, j != k, a_j + a_k = a_i]

- yellow is main iteration in array,
- green j,k combinations,
- black are mirror combination,
- red are j = k,
- in each iteration we need to insert new combinations from orange vertical column